# Unable to install Free Pascal 2.6.0 on OS X 10.7.3 with Xcode 4.3

Tags: delphi, xcode4, installation, delphi-xe2, freepascal

I am trying to install Free Pascal 2.6.0 on a Mac running OSX 10.7.3 and XCode 4.3 (to be used by Delphi XE2 Update 4). The installer for Free Pascal does not allows to install itself to my hard drive. The error message displayed:

"Free Pascal Compiler 2.6.0 can't be installed on this disk. You have to install the Mac OS X developer tools (Xcode) before installing this package. When installing XCode 3.x or 4.x, make sure to install support for UNIX development (it is installed by default, but you can uncheck it)."

I do have Xcode installed and running. When I installed Xcode (through the Mac App Store) it did not showed any option (and dialog) to deselect UNIX development.

While searching for solution I found someone with a similar problem. In that case uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode resolved the issue. However I don't know how to uninstall Xcode. I can not find "uninstall-devtools".

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have it here, but IIRC, the notes that come with update 4 say that you can only use Firemonkey for iOS and FPC with Xcode 4.2, not with 4.3. So I guess your only chance is to install 4.2 again. AFAIK, it is possible to have both 4.2 and 4.3 on the same machine.

Comment: I have both on my machine. IIRC,  XCode 4.3 is installed as a single in place app bundle in the main Applications folder,  (Xcode.app is really a folder containing all the sub-applications including Instruments etc), whereas 4.2 is installed under the /Developer folder, and they don't interfere at all. After the 4.3 installation it gives you the option to delete the old tools. If you do that, you can't use Firemonkey+iOS stuff anymore.

Comment: Thanks Rudy. I installed XCode 4.2.1. The FreePascal installer now recognizes my hard drive as target but the installation fails "There were errors with the installation". However your answer is correct for my original question.

Comment: FYI after uninstalling and installing XCode 4.2.1 FreePascal installed successfully.

Comment: Where did you find 4.2.1 that installs on Lion? Developer downloads give me only Xcode 4.3.1 for Lion (which is not supported by FPC) and Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard (which doesn't install on Lion).

Comment: Try http://connect.apple.com. I found 4.2.1 for Lion there. You can only get it if you can sign in there.

Answer (score 2):

After installing *Xcode 4.3.x* you also need to install the **Unix command line tools**.

Do this by starting XCode, then in the *Preferences -> Downloads* make sure that you install the option *Command Line Tools*.

*(solution from Lazarus forum)*